# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copier'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, installation, pip

Goal: to run program with `copier` dependency.

`pip install copier`:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager/pwmf/cli$ pip install copier
cd .Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
.Requirement already satisfied: copier in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.1.0)
/Requirement already satisfied: colorama<0.5.0,>=0.4.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from copier) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: plumbum<2.0.0,>=1.6.9 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml<6.0.0,>=5.3.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from copier) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex<2021.0.0,>=2020.6.8 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (2020.11.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic<2.0.0,>=1.5.1 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<3.0.0,>=2.11.2 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pathspec<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml-include<2.0,>=1.2 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (1.2.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging<21.0,>=20.4 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from copier) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from jinja2<3.0.0,>=2.11.2->copier) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from packaging<21.0,>=20.4->copier) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pydantic<2.0.0,>=1.5.1->copier) (4.0.1)
..WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager/pwmf/cli$ cd ../../
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$ poetry run python pwmf/cli/cli.py  new-worker -n experiment_worker -o ../../workers-python/workers/ -t basic_worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pwmf/cli/cli.py", line 8, in <module>
    from copier import copy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copier'
```

`poetry add copier`:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$ poetry add copier
The following packages are already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped:

  • copier

If you want to update it to the latest compatible version, you can use `poetry update package`.
If you prefer to upgrade it to the latest available version, you can use `poetry add package@latest`.

Nothing to add.
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$ poetry run python pwmf/cli/cli.py  new-worker -n experiment_worker -o ../../workers-python/workers/ -t basic_worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pwmf/cli/cli.py", line 8, in <module>
    from copier import copy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copier'
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$
```

`poetry update copier`:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$ poetry update copier
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1.6s)

  SSLError

  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/dagster-aws/0.9.22.post0/json (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)')))

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/requests/adapters.py:514 in send
      510│                 raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
      511│
      512│             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
      513│                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
    → 514│                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
      515│
      516│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      517│
      518│         except ClosedPoolError as e:
```

`poetry add copier@latest`:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$ poetry add copier@latest
Using version ^5.1.0 for copier

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1241.3s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 72 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing pymongo (3.12.0): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Invalid hashes (sha256:44a15fadb9c3f35c8d2af0acea375c7c4c45877c137934a8667d82f900951e36) for pymongo (3.12.0) using archive pymongo-3.12.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl. Expected one of sha256:02dc0b0f48ed3cd06c13b7e31b066bf91e00dac5f8147b0a0a45f9009bfab857, sha256:053b4ebf91c7395d1fcd2ce6a9edff0024575b7b2de6781554a4114448a8adc9, sha256:070a4ef689c9438a999ec3830e69b208ff0d12251846e064d947f97d819d1d05, sha256:072ba7cb65c8aa4d5c5659bf6722ee85781c9d7816dc00679b8b6f3dff1ddafc, sha256:0b6055e0ef451ff73c93d0348d122a0750dddf323b9361de5835dac2f6cf7fc1, sha256:11f9e0cfc84ade088a38df2708d0b958bb76360181df1b2e1e1a41beaa57952b, sha256:18290649759f9db660972442aa606f845c368db9b08c4c73770f6da14113569b, sha256:186104a94d39b8412f8e3de385acd990a628346a4402d4f3a288a82b8660bd22, sha256:1970cfe2aec1bf74b40cf30c130ad10cd968941694630386db33e1d044c22a2e, sha256:19d4bd0fc29aa405bb1781456c9cfff9fceabb68543741eb17234952dbc2bbb0, sha256:1bab889ae7640eba739f67fcbf8eff252dddc60d4495e6ddd3a87cd9a95fdb52, sha256:1bc6fe7279ff40c6818db002bf5284aa03ec181ea1b1ceaeee33c289d412afa7, sha256:208debdcf76ed39ebf24f38509f50dc1c100e31e8653817fedb8e1f867850a13, sha256:2399a85b54f68008e483b2871f4a458b4c980469c7fe921595ede073e4844f1e, sha256:246ec420e4c8744fceb4e259f906211b9c198e1f345e6158dcd7cbad3737e11e, sha256:24f8aeec4d6b894a6128844e50ff423dd02462ee83addf503c598ee3a80ddf3d, sha256:255a35bf29185f44b412e31a927d9dcedda7c2c380127ecc4fbf2f61b72fa978, sha256:2dbfbbded947a83a3dffc2bd1ec4750c17e40904692186e2c55a3ad314ca0222, sha256:2e92aa32300a0b5e4175caec7769f482b292769807024a86d674b3f19b8e3755, sha256:316c1b8723afa9870567cd6dff35d440b2afeda53aa13da6c5ab85f98ed6f5ca, sha256:333bfad77aa9cd11711febfb75eed0bb537a1d022e1c252714dad38993590240, sha256:39dafa2eaf577d1969f289dc9a44501859a1897eb45bd589e93ce843fc610800, sha256:3ce83f17f641a62a4dfb0ba1b8a3c1ced7c842f511b5450d90c030c7828e3693, sha256:46d5ec90276f71af3a29917b30f2aec2315a2759b5f8d45b3b63a07ca8a070a3, sha256:48d5bc80ab0af6b60c4163c5617f5cd23f2f880d7600940870ea5055816af024, sha256:4ba0def4abef058c0e5101e05e3d5266e6fffb9795bbf8be0fe912a7361a0209, sha256:5af390fa9faf56c93252dab09ea57cd020c9123aa921b63a0ed51832fdb492e7, sha256:5e574664f1468872cd40f74e4811e22b1aa4de9399d6bcfdf1ee6ea94c017fcf, sha256:625befa3bc9b40746a749115cc6a15bf20b9bd7597ca55d646205b479a2c99c7, sha256:6261bee7c5abadeac7497f8f1c43e521da78dd13b0a2439f526a7b0fc3788824, sha256:657ad80de8ec9ed656f28844efc801a0802961e8c6a85038d97ff6f555ef4919, sha256:6b89dc51206e4971c5568c797991eaaef5dc2a6118d67165858ad11752dba055, sha256:6e66780f14c2efaf989cd3ac613b03ee6a8e3a0ba7b96c0bb14adca71a427e55, sha256:6fb3f85870ae26896bb44e67db94045f2ebf00c5d41e6b66cdcbb5afd644fc18, sha256:701e08457183da70ed96b35a6b43e6ba1df0b47c837b063cde39a1fbe1aeda81, sha256:70761fd3c576b027eec882b43ee0a8e5b22ff9c20cdf4d0400e104bc29e53e34, sha256:73b400fdc22de84bae0dbf1a22613928a41612ec0a3d6ed47caf7ad4d3d0f2ff, sha256:7412a36798966624dc4c57d64aa43c2d1100b348abd98daaac8e99e57d87e1d7, sha256:78ecb8d42f50d393af912bfb1fb1dcc9aabe9967973efb49ee577e8f1cea494c, sha256:7c6a9948916a7bbcc6d3a9f6fb75db1acb5546078023bfb3db6efabcd5a67527, sha256:7c72d08acdf573455b2b9d2b75b8237654841d63a48bc2327dc102c6ee89b75a, sha256:7d98ce3c42921bb91566121b658e0d9d59a9082a9bd6f473190607ff25ab637f, sha256:845a8b83798b2fb11b09928413cb32692866bfbc28830a433d9fa4c8c3720dd0, sha256:94d38eba4d1b5eb3e6bfece0651b855a35c44f32fd91f512ab4ba41b8c0d3e66, sha256:9a13661681d17e43009bb3e85e837aa1ec5feeea1e3654682a01b8821940f8b3, sha256:a0e5dff6701fa615f165306e642709e1c1550d5b237c5a7a6ea299886828bd50, sha256:a2239556ff7241584ce57be1facf25081669bb457a9e5cbe68cce4aae6567aa1, sha256:a325600c83e61e3c9cebc0c2b1c8c4140fa887f789085075e8f44c8ff2547eb9, sha256:a3566acfbcde46911c52810374ecc0354fdb841284a3efef6ff7105bc007e9a8, sha256:a634a4730ce0b0934ed75e45beba730968e12b4dafbb22f69b3b2f616d9e644e, sha256:a6d055f01b83b1a4df8bb0c61983d3bdffa913764488910af3620e5c2450bf83, sha256:a752ecd1a26000a6d67be7c9a2e93801994a8b3f866ac95b672fbc00225ca91a, sha256:a9ba2a63777027b06b116e1ea8248e66fd1bedc2c644f93124b81a91ddbf6d88, sha256:aaa038eafb7186a4abbb311fcf20724be9363645882bbce540bef4797e812a7a, sha256:af586e85144023686fb0af09c8cdf672484ea182f352e7ceead3d832de381e1b, sha256:b0a0cf39f589e52d801fdef418305562bc030cdf8929217463c8433c65fd5c2f, sha256:b1c4874331ab960429caca81acb9d2932170d66d6d6f87e65dc4507a85aca152, sha256:b3b5b3cbc3fdf4fcfa292529df2a85b5d9c7053913a739d3069af1e12e12219f, sha256:b542d56ed1b8d5cf3bb36326f814bd2fbe8812dfd2582b80a15689ea433c0e35, sha256:b6ea08758b6673610b3c5bdf47189286cf9c58b1077558706a2f6f8744922527, sha256:b754240daafecd9d5fce426b0fbaaed03f4ebb130745c8a4ae9231fffb8d75e5, sha256:b772bab31cbd9cb911e41e1a611ebc9497f9a32a7348e2747c38210f75c00f41, sha256:b88d1742159bc93a078733f9789f563cef26f5e370eba810476a71aa98e5fbc2, sha256:b8bf42d3b32f586f4c9e37541769993783a534ad35531ce8a4379f6fa664fba9, sha256:bc9ac81e73573516070d24ce15da91281922811f385645df32bd3c8a45ab4684, sha256:c188db6cf9e14dbbb42f5254292be96f05374a35e7dfa087cc2140f0ff4f10f6, sha256:c55782a55f4a013a78ac5b6ee4b8731a192dea7ab09f1b6b3044c96d5128edd4, sha256:c5cab230e7cabdae9ff23c12271231283efefb944c1b79bed79a91beb65ba547, sha256:cbf8672edeb7b7128c4a939274801f0e32bbf5159987815e3d1eace625264a46, sha256:cc2894fe91f31a513860238ede69fe47fada21f9e7ddfe73f7f9fef93a971e41, sha256:cda9e628b1315beec8341e8c04aac9a0b910650b05e0751e42e399d5694aeacb, sha256:ceae3ab9e11a27aaab42878f1d203600dfd24f0e43678b47298219a0f10c0d30, sha256:ced944dcdd561476deef7cb7bfd4987c69fffbfeff6d02ca4d5d4fd592d559b7, sha256:d04ca462cb99077e6c059e97c072957caf2918e6e4191e3161c01c439e0193de, sha256:d1131562ddc2ea8a446f66c2648d7dabec2b3816fc818528eb978a75a6d23b2e, sha256:d1740776b70367277323fafb76bcf09753a5cc9824f5d705bac22a34ff3668ea, sha256:d6e11ffd43184d529d6752d6dcb62b994f903038a17ea2168ef1910c96324d26, sha256:d73e10772152605f6648ba4410318594f1043bbfe36d2fadee7c4b8912eff7c5, sha256:da8288bc4a7807c6715416deed1c57d94d5e03e93537889e002bf985be503f1a, sha256:db93608a246da44d728842b8fa9e45aa9782db76955f634a707739a8d53ff544, sha256:dcd3d0009fbb6e454d729f8b22d0063bd9171c31a55e0f0271119bd4f2700023, sha256:dd1f49f949a658c4e8f81ed73f9aad25fcc7d4f62f767f591e749e30038c4e1d, sha256:dd6ff2192f34bd622883c745a56f492b1c9ccd44e14953e8051c33024a2947d5, sha256:e018a4921657c2d3f89c720b7b90b9182e277178a04a7e9542cc79d7d787ca51, sha256:e2b7670c0c8c6b501464150dd49dd0d6be6cb7f049e064124911cec5514fa19e, sha256:e7a33322e08021c37e89cae8ff06327503e8a1719e97c69f32c31cbf6c30d72c, sha256:e8a82e35d52ad6f867e88096a1a2b9bdc7ec4d5e65c7b4976a248bf2d1a32a93, sha256:e9faf8d4712d5ea301d74abfcf6dafe4b7f4af7936e91f283b0ad7bf69ed3e3a, sha256:ec5ca7c0007ce268048bbe0ffc6846ed1616cf3d8628b136e81d5e64ff3f52a2, sha256:eee42a1cc06565f6b21caa1f504ec15e07de7ebfd520ab57f8cb3308bc118e22, sha256:f2acf9bbcd514e901f82c4ca6926bbd2ae61716728f110b4343eb0a69612d018, sha256:f55c1ddcc1f6050b07d468ce594f55dbf6107b459e16f735d26818d7be1e9538, sha256:f6977a520bd96e097c8a37a8cbb9faa1ea99d21bf84190195056e25f688af73d, sha256:f94c7d22fb36b184734dded7345a04ec5f95130421c775b8b0c65044ef073f34, sha256:fa8957e9a1b202cb45e6b839c241cd986c897be1e722b81d2f32e9c6aeee80b0, sha256:fd3854148005c808c485c754a184c71116372263709958b42aefbef2e5dd373a, sha256:fe5872ce6f9627deac8314bdffd3862624227c3de4c17ef0cc78bbf0402999eb, sha256:ffbae429ba9e42d0582d3ac63fdb410338892468a2107d8ff68228ec9a39a0ed.

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/installation/executor.py:627 in _download_link
      623│                     )
      624│                 )
      625│
      626│             if archive_hashes.isdisjoint(hashes):
    → 627│                 raise RuntimeError(
      628│                     "Invalid hashes ({}) for {} using archive {}. Expected one of {}.".format(
      629│                         ", ".join(sorted(archive_hashes)),
      630│                         package,
      631│                         archive_path.name,


Failed to add packages, reverting the pyproject.toml file to its original content.
```

`poetry install copier`:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python-framework/workers_manager$ poetry install copier
Too many arguments.
```

Comment: [Git Issue](https://github.com/copier-org/copier/issues/563)

Comment: Copier Git Issue suggests its a [Poetry issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5165)

Answer (score 0):

You have installed to your systems python instead of the one associated with your venve that `poetry run` probably uses. Since you are using `poetry`, you should try installing with

```
 poetry add copier
```

Comment: That's a shout! However, this didn't work for me ;( Check updated post

Comment: I've setup 2 Git Issues, each for `copier` and `poetry`. Poetry told me `poetry add copier` wouldn't help. Re-cloning didn't help either ;(